# WCF application crash on passing IList

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, rest, asp.net-3.5

I crated a WCF .Net 3.5 Rest service, it crashes when I pass `IList` interface. I'm using NHibernate to populate the list.

Here is my code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "EconService/GetAllLanguage", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public IList<Language> GetAllLanguage()
{
   IList<Language> rtnLang = Language.GetAll();
   return rtnLang;
}
```

This is the error message:

> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Cannot serialize parameter of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Econcordia.Language]' (for
>   operation 'GetLanguage', contract 'Service1') because it is not the
>   exact type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Econcordia.Language]'
>   in the method signature and is not in the known types collection. In
>   order to serialize the parameter, add the type to the known types
>   collection for the operation using ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.'. See
>   server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.ValidateOutputType(Type
>   type, Type parameterType, IList`1 knownTypes)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.GetOutputSerializer(Type type)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.CreateBodyWriter(Object
>   body)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion
>   messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ContentTypeSettingDispatchMessageFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion
>   messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.SerializeOutputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question with the error message.

Comment: `IList` is really an **interface** - not an object....

Comment: I have `[OperationContract]`s which return `IEnumerable<Whatever>` all over the place and have no problems with them.  They're either `List<Whatever>` or `Whatever[]` in the code, but the return type works just fine in WCF for me.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry! my bad. I edited the question.

Comment: @Jesse: Exact same code worked on .Net 4 but it failed to work on 3.5! I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a concrete `List<Language>` instead.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "EconService/GetAllLanguage", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<Language> GetAllLanguage()
{
    IList<Language> rtnLang = Language.GetAll();
    return rtnLang.ToList();
}
```

Hope it works.